# odp net oracle parameter constructor with boolean object

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net

I am using the odp OracleParameter constructor:

```
public OracleParameter(string parameterName, object obj);
```

When i pass different types as objects like int or DateTime it works fine.
However when i use bool like this:

```
new OracleParameter("paramName", true)
```

it crashes with a "System.ArgumentException".

Why does this not work with bool values?
Are there known types where this does not work?

I am using Oracle ManagedDataAccess.dll v4.121.2.0

Comment: what you do in your constructor with the input values?

Comment: It is not my own constructor. It is from odp .NET [link](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/OracleParameterClass.htm#i1011308)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle does not support `bool` values as a DataType for it's columns. PL/SQL is another matter.

You first have to check the datatype of your `bool` field/parameter in Oracle.

If it's something like `NUMBER` use the following code:

```
new OracleParameter("paramName", OracleDbType.Int16, 1);
```

Here the third paremeter is the size of the `NUMBER` value.

As you mentionned in your comments, you can use this [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/OracleParameterClass.htm#i1011428):

```
public OracleParameter(string parameterName, OracleDbType type, object obj, 
   ParameterDirection direction);
```

Which allows you to skip defining the size.

---

Otherwise I would convert it to `NUMBER` since the `OracleDbType` enum does not contain a value for `BOOLEAN`.

I always specify the OracleDbType when creating a new Oracle parameter. It makes things more explicit and prevent errors of the sort.

Comment: Thank you that was one part of the information I needed. Where do I get these information’s other than stumbling upon them? Are there other types where this does not work?

Comment: @DanF As for other types where this does not work, I can't think of any right now. It's a good practice to specify the type for all parameters by the way and besides the bool type most are pretty self explanatory. If this solved your problem, please mark the answer as accepted. Thanks.

Comment: You posted the wrong constructor. The one needed ist this one [link](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/OracleParameterClass.htm#i1011428)

Comment: @DanF I am currently using the constructor with the direction parameters only when I am using Out parameters. Otherwise, I use the one I posted in my answer for In parameter though there is no harm in using the one with the direction parameter for In parameters as well.

Comment: I tried the one you posted, but the third int parameter is marked as size by the oracle documentation [link](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/OracleParameterClass.htm#i1011493). That is why I used the other one. The one you posted is not working within my projects. Maybe we use different libraries?

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to go into redundancy explaining Oracle DB. But want you to understand that Oracle types don't natch .NET types like Sql Server types do match.

For example, to fit `int` value into Oracle, you need to create column `NUMBER(10)`. This size however is larger than `int` and when you do `Select col1. . .` it returns `long`. So, you need to do `Convert.ToInt32(reader["col1"])` to "fit" your data into `int` in your application.

Same thing with boolean here. There is no exact type. Sometimes people store fake booleans in `Number(1)`, or even in `Varchar2(1)` as "Y"/"N" (for example). So, if your DB has some numeric data type, just do

```
bool val = GetVal();
var p = new OracleParameter("paramName", Convert.ToInt32(val))
```

It will give you `1` for `true` and `0` for `false`